# I need to find mail app for Android which can work with maildir format messages

Tags: android, email, email-client

I have online synced dropbox folder with messages in [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) e-mail format. Is any convenient mail application which I can use for work with this folder on android mobile phone?

Thank you!

Comment: i'm not sure if this is even possible... i better suggest to simply **use an IMAP-account**!?